# How to wrap a C++ functor in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython, functor

I'm trying to wrap a C++ library in which the logic is implemented as templatized functors in `.hpp` files, and I'm struggling to find the right way to expose the C++ functors as Cython/Python functions. How are functors like the one below supposed to be wrapped in Cython?

I believe this should be possible, at least for template classes and functions, according to the [Cython 0.20 docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#templates).

**Note:** I think I've figured out how to wrap normal C++ functions—the problem occurs when I'm trying to wrap a templatized **functor**, *i.e.* a template `struct` that overloads the `()` operator (making it act like a function when a data type is fixed).

*Disclaimer:* I'm a total novice in C++ and very new to Cython so apologies if I'm making obvious mistakes here.

---

#### The functor I'm trying to wrap:

```
#include <vector>
#include "EMD_DEFS.hpp"
#include "flow_utils.hpp"

template<typename NUM_T, FLOW_TYPE_T FLOW_TYPE= NO_FLOW>
struct emd_hat_gd_metric {
    NUM_T operator()(const std::vector<NUM_T>& P, const std::vector<NUM_T>& Q,
                     const std::vector< std::vector<NUM_T> >& C,
                     NUM_T extra_mass_penalty= -1,
                     std::vector< std::vector<NUM_T> >* F= NULL);
};
```

#### My `wrapper.pyx` file:

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector


cdef extern from "lib/emd_hat.hpp":
    # Apparently `cppclass` is necessary here even though 
    # `emd_hat_gd_metric` is not a class...?
    cdef cppclass emd_hat_gd_metric[NUM_T]:
        NUM_T operator()(vector[NUM_T]& P,
                         vector[NUM_T]& Q,
                         vector[vector[NUM_T]]& C) except +

cdef class EMD:

    cdef emd_hat_gd_metric *__thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.__thisptr = new emd_hat_gd_metric()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.__thisptr

    def calculate(self, P, Q, C):
        # What goes here? How do I call the functor as a function?
        return self.__thisptr(P, Q, C)
```

The above just gives a `Calling non-function type 'emd_hat_gd_metric[NUM_T]'` error when I try to compile it with `cython --cplus wrapper.pyx`.

[Here's the full library I'm trying to wrap.](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ofirpele/FastEMD/code/)

**End goal:** to be able to call `emd_hat_gd_metric` as a Cython/Python function, with arguments being NumPy arrays.

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE ?

Comment: @hivert, I found a workaround—see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a real solution, but here's a workaround (that requires modifying the C++ code): just instantiate the template function with the data type you need in the C++ header, then declare that function normally in your `.pyx` file.

It's a little unwieldy if you need many different data types, but I only needed `double`. It would also be nicer if it wasn't necessary to modify the external library… but it works.

---

#### In the C++ `some_library.hpp` file:

Instantiate the functor with the data type you need (say, `double`):

```
template<typename T>
struct some_template_functor {
    T operator()(T x);
};

// Add this:
some_template_functor<double> some_template_functor_double;
```

#### In the Cython `.pyx` file:

Declare the function normally (no need for `cppclass`):

```
cdef extern from "path/to/some_library.hpp":
    cdef double some_template_functor_double(double x)
```

Then you can call `some_template_functor_double` from within Cython.